# Turbogears 2 Tutorials?

Tags: python, sql-server, turbogears, turbogears2

Anyone know of a good beginners tutorial for Turbogears 2? I'm particularly interested in one that would have some details on working with existing database schema rather than creating from scratch. (and some pointers on MS SQL server setup would help too!)

Comment: For the database stuff you need to look at SQLAlchemy documentation and perhaps pyodbc. You merely need to ignore the bits in the existing tutorial that issue 'CREATE TABLE' statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good TG2 tutorial is the movie demo http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/RestControllers.html. It walks you into the basics of what a "high level" TG2 app is.

Regarding your MS SQL question I agree with joeforker, this is more a SA issue than TG. You have several options the best is the *very* experimental code put together by Chris Perkins, based on [autocode](http://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/) and some snips from myself. This currently works well with postgres and sqlite, we'll love some MS SQL patches :) http://bitbucket.org/percious/sqlautocode/

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.fruiapps.com/2012/05/TurboGears2-tutorial-to-create-a-simple-MVC-application) tutorial talks about, making a simple note taking application using TurboGears2. Its directed towards beginners, you will find it useful.